# Replace word with link in php

Tags: php, html, datalife-engine

I need to replace this html code:

```
Actors: Mamoru Miyano, Kappei Yamaguchi, Aya Hirano
```

with this code:

```
Actors: <a href="http://example.com/actor/Mamoru Miyano">Mamoru Miyano</a>, <a href="http://example.com/actor/Kappei Yamaguchi">Kappei Yamaguchi</a>, <a href="http://example.com/actor/Aya Hirano">Aya Hirano</a>
```

Is it possible?

In control panel i cannot see actors list i see only this: [xfvalue_actors]

and i tried to replace as this:

```
<a href="http://myfilms.ga/actor/<?php $str = '[xfvalue_actors]'; echo preg_replace('/, /', '"></a><a href="http://myfilms.ga/actor/', $str, 20); ?>/">[xfvalue_actors]</a><br />
```

but i get it:

```
<a href="http://myfilms.ga/actor/Mamoru Miyano"></a><a href="http://myfilms.ga/actor/Kappei Yamaguchi"></a><a href="http://myfilms.ga/actor/Aya Hirano">Mamoru Miyano, Kappei Yamaguchi, Aya Hirano</a><br />
```

Comment: Can you modify the macro that renders `[xfvalue_actors]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this and tell me how it is working?

```
<?php 
$str = '[xfvalue_actors]'; 
$arrActors = explode(',', $str);
$out = '';
foreach ($arrActors as $actor) {
    $out .= "<a href='http://myfilms.ga/actor/{$actor}'>{$actor}</a><br />,";
}
echo "Actors: " . substr($out, 0, -1);
?>
```

As a result I am getting:

`Actors: <a href='http://myfilms.ga/actor/Mamoru Miyano'>Mamoru Miyano</a><br />,<a href='http://myfilms.ga/actor/ Kappei Yamaguchi'> Kappei Yamaguchi</a><br />,<a href='http://myfilms.ga/actor/ Aya Hirano'> Aya Hirano</a><br />`

Hope this is what you need! :)

Comment: <a href='http://myfilms.ga/actor/Mamoru Miyano,  Kappei Yamaguchi,  Aya Hirano'>Mamoru Miyano,  Kappei Yamaguchi,  Aya Hirano</a>

This

Comment: Check the modified answer - it is tested! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_replace` if you want to replace a part of string

```
$old = "Actors: Mamoru Miyano, Kappei Yamaguchi, Aya Hirano";
$new = "Actors: <a href="http://example.com/actor/Mamoru Miyano>Mamoru Miyano</a>, <a href="http://example.com/actor/Kappei Yamaguchi>Kappei Yamaguchi</a>, <a href="http://example.com/actor/Aya Hirano>Aya Hirano</a>";


str_replace($old,$new,$your_string)
```

But in your case you are referring to HTML . so may be you can use jquery

```
var replaced = $("body").html().replace('Actors: Mamoru Miyano, Kappei Yamaguchi, Aya Hirano','The new string');
$("body").html(replaced);
```

Comment: In Admin Panel
This: Mamoru Miyano, Kappei Yamaguchi, Aya Hirano
Looks as: {actors}

so i cannot replace it so easy

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to change based on a certain condition..try if loop(php)

```
<?php if(condition){ ?> Actors: <a href="http://example.com/actor/Mamoru Miyano>Mamoru Miyano</a>, <a href="http://example.com/actor/Kappei Yamaguchi>Kappei Yamaguchi</a>, <a href="http://example.com/actor/Aya Hirano>Aya Hirano</a><?php }else { ?>Actors: Mamoru Miyano, Kappei Yamaguchi, Aya Hirano <?php } ?>
```

Comment: there's an if loop? :D